# Media queries do not apply when resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a media queries problem. I want to change the `width` property of container to `100%` of page, but it's not applying. I use bootstrap as CSS framework. I give you a shot from inspector:[image: Image of resized page with inspector]

Code:

```
<div class="container-flex" id="blog-posts">
    <div class="post-left">
        <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/content/blog/post-image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
        <div class="divider-dot"></div>
        <div class="divider-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-right">
        <div>
            <time>10 April 2014</time>
            <h3>Typi non habent claritatem insitam</h3>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendreit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui [...]</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
    #blog-posts {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid blue;

        .divider {
            display: none;
        }

        .post-left {
            ;
            width: 100%;

            div {
                //width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid;
            }
        }

        .post-right {
            width: 100%;

            div {
                width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
#blog-posts {
    display: flex;

    .post-left {
        width: 47.95%;
        //border: 1px solid blue;
        div {
            width: 50%;
            float: right;

            img {
                float: right;
            }
        }
    }

    .divider {
        //border: 1px solid;
        width: 4.1%;

        .divider-dot {
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
            width: 17px;
            height: 17px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .divider-line {
            width: 1px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    .post-right {
        //border: 1px solid green;
        width: 47.95%;

        div {
            width: 50%;

            time {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: "Raleway";
                color: rgb(123, 108, 99);
                line-height: 1.875;
                text-align: left;
            }

            h3 {
                font-size: 24px;
                font-family: "Raleway";
                color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
                line-height: 1.25;
                text-align: left;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: "Raleway";
                color: rgb(148, 148, 148);
                line-height: 1.875;
                text-align: left;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you put your media queries after your actual styles, otherwise it won't be inheritable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments: media-queries should come after your default styles. Since they have to overwrite them.

Your code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  #blog-posts{
    // styles...
  }
}

#blog-posts{
  // styles...
}
```

Should be:

```
#blog-posts{
  // styles...
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  #blog-posts{
    // styles...
  }
}
```

---

You can simply demonstrate this behavior by overwriting a class

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.color {
  background: red;
}
.color {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="color"></div>
```

As you can see, the block is green instead of red.

You can apply the same rule to media-queries, with the exception that they only apply when the viewport is larger than the given size.

Comment: I moved media queries to the bottom of css file. Now it works great. Thank you and vote up.

Answer (score -1):

Your style in the media query is being overwritten by another rule down in your scss file.

Try moving that media query block to the end of your style.scss file.

#### Edit

That happens because you are first defining the rule for your media query and **later in your code** you have another rule for the same selector, that's basically overriding your previous rule.

To give you a generic example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .my-class {
        color: red;
    }
}

.my-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

Any element with class `my-class` will have a color `blue`, no matter the size of the screen. The last rule defined will override your previous one.
Now, let's change the order of those rules:

```
.my-class {
    color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .my-class {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

In this case, every element with class `my-class` will have a color `blue` if the screen size is at least 768px. If the screen size drops below 768px, your media query rule will **override** your previous rule, giving a color of `red`.

Just to be clear, this is not the only solution.
Another solution would be to set `!important` in your media query. But you should **avoid** using `!important` if you have other solutions.

Another possible solution would be to wrap your class inside another media query (in this case the order doesn't matter).

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .my-class {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-class {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not downvoter, but this answer should be a comment. [answer]

Answer (score -3):

Add !important in the end of width:100% important